# How to simulate an Escape event that listen to event on window using in react(enzyme & jest)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, react-typescript

Despite everything that I could find online, still not finding a working solution on how to simulate an Escape keyboard event.
my component shorten look like this one

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
   useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
      console.log(event);
    });
   return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
       console.log(event);
     });
  };
},  []);

return <div className="App">click a key</div>;}
```

I have mostly material ui component like Dialog, IconButton, Box, Typogreaphy, ... and can not rely on an input field
[link to a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-antonelli-7rwk8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js:0-381)

Comment: it should be `window.removeEventListener('keydown')` for clean up.

Comment: Hey, Thx just copy pasting and forget to remove it  @slideshowp2

Answer (score 0):

```
  it('calls setShowModal on escape key', () => {
    render(<ModalPopUp {...props}>children</ModalPopUp>)
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'Escape' })
    document.dispatchEvent(event)
    expect(props.setShowModal).toBeCalled()
  })
```

You can use it with this way